# multiple loops on matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, lapply

I have below information:

```
coordinate <- read.table(text = " 18.915 13.462 31.598
 17.898 14.453 32.160
                          18.220 15.420 32.853
                          19.208 12.313 32.573
                          20.393 11.524 32.110
                          20.344 10.809 31.085
                          21.595 16.610 29.912")
amnumber <- c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4)

atname <-as.data.frame( c("A","B","A","C","D","C","H"),stringsAsFactors = F)


library(geometry)
tri <- delaunayn(coordinate)
tri
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    7    2
[2,]    4    1    6    2
[3,]    4    1    3    2
[4,]    4    1    3    7
[5,]    5    4    3    7
[6,]    5    1    6    7
[7,]    5    4    1    7
[8,]    5    4    1    6

tridmatrix
```

I want to perform two loops on tri mamtrix such that value 1 in the first row has relations between each other next values like 3,7 and 2. So, in the output matrix of our loops, we have to put 1 between these indices. Then, value 3 of the first row has relations between two other values like 7 and 2. And so on. The output result would be a matrix that only contains 0,1 values. To this end I wrote the below loops:

```
for (k in 1:nrow(tri)){
  for (i in 1:4){
    for (j in i+1){

      c <- abs(amnumber[tri[k,i]]-amnumber[tri[k,j]])

      if (c>=1){

        if (!((atname[tri[k,i],]%in%"N")&&(atname[tri[k,j],]%in%"C")&&(c%in%1)||
              (atname[tri[k,i],]%in%"C")&&(atname[tri[k,j],]%in%"N")&&(c%in%1))){

          d <- sqrt(sum((coordinate[tri[k,i],]-coordinate[tri[k,j],])^2))

          if (d<=tridist){
            adj_tri[tri[k,i],tri[k,j]] <- 1
            adj_tri[tri[k,j],tri[k,i]] <- 1
            adj_tri[is.na(adj_tri)] <- 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it did not work. And I faced error. i index is equal to the number of columns in tri matrix and I think the problem is in the third loop. However, I could not fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Besides, this is too slow. Would you please help me to change it lapply to speed up the progress.

Comment: Could you add how your desired output matrix should look like? I did not get it from your description.

Comment: A potential source of error might be the j-loop. Your matrix has only 4 columns, however, the last run of the loop uses a value of `j = 4+1 = 5`.

Comment: @ManuelBickel I think so but how can i fix it?

Comment: This depends on the desired output. As stated by the previous comment, it is not clear how your output should look like. It would be helpful if you could provide an example.